# Calling java parent method from Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

Say I have a java library with the following pseudo code :

```
abstract class B {
    public void method2(String param2) {...}
}

class A extends B {
    public void method1(String param1) {...}
}
```

I want to use this from Clojure.

I have an instance of A, and I want to invoke method2 without going through Reflection methods.

What's the quickest way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an instance of A you can just call `method2` using normal interop:

```
(.method2 (A.) "param")
```

Comment: I am going to mark your answer correct regarding my own question; my real problem was that the method was actually protected not public, so I had to go through reflection.